# Creating an atlas of 3D map scenes in QGIS based on a point layer with camera information

Tags: qgis, 3d

Is it possible to create an atlas of 3D maps in QGIS where the the camera pose for each map is set using values from a point layer? Ultimately, I'm in interested in generating photomontages between the exported 3D maps and photographs - so would need to be able to match field of view, direction and location of the export to those taken by the camera.

Would consider a scripted solution. I've just started exploring QGIS's 3D capabilities but a quick look at the atlas settings in layout suggests that this isn't available out of the box. I'm also a little confused as to what the Camera Pose settings actually mean (what is Distance in this context? Are the Center values the position of the camera or the 3D map?).